# my anonymous function in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

On about line 18, make the anonymous function with the code 'window.didExecute = true' execute.

```
  var anonymousFunction = function(){};

  (function(){window.didExecute=true;})
```

doesn't work, why?

Comment: You need to add `()` after your function. (`(function(){window.didExecute=true;})()`). Or remove the `(` `)` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function is never executed. Use an immediately invoked function expression:

```
(function(){window.didExecute=true;})();
```

The `()` at the end is what actually makes it a function call, resulting in the body of the function executing.

If you weren't using anonymous functions, your code would be the same as doing:

```
function foo() {
    window.didExecute = true;
}
```

Then never calling `foo()`.